# Split-plot Repeated measures anova, Linear regression and different Results in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

This question here came after a long research about the subject. I'll appreciate your reply.

I conducted a research and now my goal is to test the effect of the **Treatment** on the **ouctome**, but I want to check the **moderation effect of the Race**.

```
n treatment: 83 
n placebo: 76
No missings.
```

My original dataset is in Wide format.
[image: Wide format]

Where:

```
**ID -> Participant identification
Con_dummy -> Treatment or Control (Between subjects)
Hispanic -> Yes or no (Between subjects)
M41 and M_42 -> Dependent variables. M_41 was measured in 2016 and M_42 was measures in 2017.**
```

I transformed my dataset to a long format using this code:

> ```
> d2_stack_long <- df_stack %>%    group_by(cond_dummy) %>%   
> select(ID, cond_dummy, hispanic, M_4I1TOT,M_4I2TOT) %>%   
> gather(key="ID", value, M_4I1TOT,M_4I2TOT) %>%    tbl_df() %>%   
> setNames(c("ID","Condition","Hispanic", "Time","Result")) %>%   
> mutate(Time = ifelse(Time == "M_4I1TOT", "Time 1", "Time 2")) %>%   
> arrange(ID)
> ```

I've got a message

> Warning message: attributes are not identical across measure
>   variables; they will be dropped

But now I have a long dataset. I have the double numbers of rows now, because every participant was measured at two time point, but everything remains the same

[image: long format]

> ```
> > d2_stack_long %>% group_by(Condition, Time) %>% summarise(mean(Result),n=n())
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   Condition [?]
>   Condition   Time `mean(Result)`     n
>       <chr>  <chr>          <dbl> <int>
> 1   Control Time 1       5.973684    76
> 2   Control Time 2       6.342105    76
> 3 Treatment Time 1       6.277108    83
> 4 Treatment Time 2       9.626506    83
> ```

When, now, I test this model, I achieve two different results when using R and when using JASP.

```
mod <- lm(data=d2_stack_long , Result ~ Time + Condition*Hispanic)
Anova(mod, type=3)
```

I think I'm forgeting to adjust something and I'll appreciate your help.
[image]

I read several posts before asking this question, but I just found people commenting about [math equation to ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-is-an-anova-calculated-for-a-repeated-measures-design-aov-vs-lm-in-r) or [comparing results across packages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264171/how-to-do-two-way-repeated-measures-anova-using-aov-in-r) like [here](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/). 
 A [famous blog](http://blog.gribblelab.org/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/) with examples is down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants the answer. After a Long journey I got from this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/split-plot-anova-model-comparison-tests-in-r).  The sums of squares type in R is set to 1, whereas in JASP it is set to 3.

You **can** add an ERROR term in Regression models (Repeated measures), despite 99% of posts here.

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.helmert", "contr.poly"))
anova(lm(Result ~ Time*Condition*Hispanic*ID, data=d2_pals_total))
```

And if you want to go with aov funcion:

```
summary(aov(data=d2_pals_total, Result ~ Time*Condition*Hispanic +
      Error(ID)))
```

Thanks